# How to create sharepoint group with custom list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have guestion regarding sharepoint groups.

I have a list for Client. Now when i add new item to Client list, the group of Client name has to be create in SharePoint. I have created an Event reciever of `ItemAdding` event.

Is it possible to do that? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the event receiver a simple google search of how to create a sharepoint 2010 user group returns several helpful tutorials.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/03/programmatically-create-user-groups-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I tried that btu it gives me an error: Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Cannot start service SPUserCodeV4 on computer 'xxxxxxxxxx'.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is a different scenario suitable for a different question.